# PHP equivalent of Python's requests.get

Tags: php, python

I'm trying to access an API using PHP but for which the tutorial is only written in Python. The tutorial shows how to retrieve the data from a URL using

res = requests.get(API_URL, auth=(UID, SECRET))

Please can someone tell me what the equivalent statement would be in PHP, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

SO is **not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service** You also have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: Google a bit about PHP curl

Comment: I did that. I saw nothing about how to incorporate the UID and SECRET parameters which the API is so insistent upon.

Comment: RiggsFolly instead of wasting time inflating your ego, you could try answering the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: To add the UID and SECRET to file_get_contents, you need to add the variables like so:

```
<?php
$UID = "UserID";
$SECRET = "Secret";
echo file_get_contents('http://apiurl.com/?UID='.$UID.'&SECRET='.$SECRET);
?>
```

So practically now the URL of file_get_contents will become: http://apiurl.com/?UID=UserID&SECRET=Secret

You can use file_get_contents, like this:

```
<?php echo file_get_contents('http://apiurl.com'); ?>
```

Or this curl function:

```
<?php
function curl_get_contents($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}
echo curl_get_contents('http://apiurl.com');
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Jade. The Python function seemed to add the UID and SECRET parameters into the API call, I'm still confused about how I would incorporate that bit into the file_get_contents.

Comment: @Bik Byro I've updated my answer, hope it helps :)

Comment: thanks for your help ! I get it now.